# prevent user from deleting all table rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, row

courtesy of a few tutorials and the SO community, I have the below syntax which dynamically adds or removes rows from table.

I want to prevent the user from being able to delete all rows in the table. I have put in an if statement to prevent deleting the first row on load, how do I get a count of all table rows to use in the if statement so I can delete all rows as long as there is at least one remaining row after deletion?

my syntax is:

```
<table class="authors-list">
  <tr><td>author's first name</td><td>author's last name</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name" /></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name" /></td><td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td></tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
jQuery("table.authors-list").on('change','input[name^="first_name"]',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name' +
        counter + '" /></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' +
        counter + '" /></td><td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
});

jQuery("table.authors-list").on('click','.deleteRow',function(event){
   console.log('h');
   if (counter==1) { alert ('form must have at least one row')} else {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 }
});
</script>
```

Thanks as always,

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/length

Comment: Why do you need an additional variable, when you can just count the rows themselves - by `$('table.authors-list').children('tr').length`, for example?

Comment: Is that all the HTML you have for the table? You've got an unclosed table, if so, which is going to create other issues for you as you go along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we meet again.....anyways

try this

```
jQuery("table.authors-list").on('click','.deleteRow',function(event){
 if ($(this).parents('table').find('tr').length >  2) { 
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 }else{
  alert ('form must have at least one row')
 }

});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/yUfhL/213/)

Comment: Absolutely awesome. I am just starting to understand the power of jquery and javascript. appreciate your time!

Comment: This also relies on hardcoding the number of excluded rows. Better markup can make the task easier to manage without hardcoding that value.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
if ($(this).closest('table').find('tr').length<2) {
   alert ('form must have at least one row')
} else {
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Comment: The only reason I don't necessarily like this method is that it relies on hardcoding the number of excluded rows... in this case, the header row and the first "untouchable" row.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't include all the markup for brevity's sake, I would be tempted to try something along these lines:

```
<table class="authors-list">
    <!-- for one thing, let's separate our table structure a little better -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>author's first name</td>
            <td>author's last name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- ... in this way, you don't have to manually exclude the header rows from your count -->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" />
            </td>
            <td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can then move on to the javascript:
(It's completely unnecessary to include the table tag in the selector... your classname should work just fine for these purposes, and saves you a few characters, btw...)

```
jQuery(".authors-list tbody").on('change', 'input[name^="first_name"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // get the number of rows, here
    var counter = $(".authors-list tbody tr").length;
    // also, you don't need to wrap newRow in a jQuery() call... append() does that for you
    var newRow = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name' + counter + '" /></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' + counter + '" /></td><td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td></tr>';
    jQuery('.authors-list tbody').append(newRow);
});

jQuery(".authors-list tbody").on('click', '.deleteRow', function (event) {
    // get the counter at the point in time when you're trying to test deletion
    var counter = $(".authors-list tbody tr").length;
    if (counter == 1) {
        alert('form must have at least one row')
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/BsaZY/2/